# Resetting the counter with jQuery/JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on the following code which dynamically generates HTML elements and where the end user is able to add and remove up to 10 optional input fields:

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plusxultra/6vRX7/4/)

Code:

```
$(function () {
var myDiv = $('#dispDiv');
var i = $('#dispDiv p').size() + 1;

$('#addScnt').click(function() {
    if (i <= 10){
    $('<p><label for="dispDiv"><input type="text" id="c_name' + i + '" size="20" name="c_name_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="c_name" /></label<br></p>').appendTo(myDiv);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Max reached");
    }


    i++;       
    return false;
});

$('#remove-btn').click(function(){
    var last = $('#dispDiv > p').last();
    last.detach();
});


});
```

The problem is that when the user adds 10 inputs and then removes them, they are not able to re-add the inputs as the 10 max input condition kicks in. I have thought about different solutions, but none have yielded a result and I'm stuck right now, do any of you have some suggestions as to how to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

You should decrease `i` when removing the input, and also just only increase `i` if `i <= 10`:

```
$(function () {
    var myDiv = $('#dispDiv');
    var i = $('#dispDiv p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').click(function () {
        if (i <= 10) {
            $('<p><label for="dispDiv"><input type="text" id="c_name' + i + '" size="20" name="c_name_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="c_name" /></label<br></p>').appendTo(myDiv);

            i++;
        } else {
            alert("Max reached");
        }

        return false;
    });

    $('#remove-btn').click(function () {
        var last = $('#dispDiv > p').last();
        last.detach();
        i--;
    });
});
```

I have updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vRX7/5/)

**Note**:

> The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the .length property instead.

Comment: this code will fail in case the user clicks remove so many times that the i becomes a negative value then clicks add => the user will be able to create more than 10 items. Managing the i variable like this is not preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some changes

1. Increment the value of `i` only if a new item is added, so move the `i++` inside the `if` block
2. On removal of the item decrement the value of `i`

Try

```
$(function () {
    var myDiv = $('#dispDiv');
    //set it to the size
    var i = $('#dispDiv p').size();

    $('#addScnt').click(function () {
        if (i < 10) {
            $('<p><label for="dispDiv"><input type="text" id="c_name' + i + '" size="20" name="c_name_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="c_name" /></label<br></p>').appendTo(myDiv);
            //increment only if new item is added
            i++;
        } else {
            alert("Max reached");
        }


        return false;
    });

    $('#remove-btn').click(function () {
        $('#dispDiv > p').last().remove();
        //decrement if removed
        if (i > 0) {
            i--;
        }
    });


});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4HKaz/)

Answer (score 0):

Hei just use a decrement in second click event handler function like that ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vRX7/8/)):

```
$(function () {
var myDiv = $('#dispDiv');
var i = $('#dispDiv p').size() + 1;

$('#addScnt').click(function() {
    if (i <= 10){
    $('<p><label for="dispDiv"><input type="text" id="c_name' + i + '" size="20" name="c_name_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="c_name" /></label<br></p>').appendTo(myDiv);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Max reached");
    }


    i++;       
    return false;
});

$('#remove-btn').click(function(){
    var last = $('#dispDiv > p').last();
    i-- ;
    last.detach();
});


});
```

Comment: this code will fail in case the user clicks remove so many times that the i becomes a negative value then clicks add => the user will be able to create more than 10 items, and more problems occur if the user clicks add when the i>10, no item is added but the i is increased. Managing the i variable like this is not preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that we need to manage the `i` variable like that. Just check for the length every time you click on `add`:

```
$(function () {
    var myDiv = $('#dispDiv');
    $('#addScnt').click(function() {
        var i = $('#dispDiv p').length + 1; //Just check for the length every time you add
        if (i <= 10){ 
        $('<p><label for="dispDiv"><input type="text" id="c_name' + i + '" size="20" name="c_name_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="c_name" /></label<br></p>').appendTo(myDiv);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Max reached");
        }

        return false;
    });

    $('#remove-btn').click(function(){
        var last = $('#dispDiv > p').last();
        last.detach();
    });
});
```

This code is simpler and easier to maintain as you don't need to manually do `i++` and `i--` to count the number of current items. This action is error-prone and may result in incorrect value when the logic becomes more complex.

***Note:***

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach()
>   keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This
>   method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the
>   DOM at a later time.

If you don't need to keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements (including event handlers), you should use remove to free all the data to save memory

```
var last = $('#dispDiv > p').last().remove();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6vRX7/16/)